# silverlight notification window location like google talk email notification

Tags: silverlight, notifications

Silverlight out of browser application has capabilities of Notification window. Is there a way to set the that notification window's position so that it will set on the bottom-right corner like google talk email notification?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Silverlight 4 it's the OS that will determine the location of the OOB  notifications (Windows = lower right / MacOS = Upper right)... not the plugin.